# custom datagridview

Tags: c#

Can you please help to create a proper custom datagrid of which, if I select any of the cell only that cell will be in edit mode and all others are in read only mode and that cell should have a data source to bind with it.

Comment: What technology is this for? Winforms? WPF? Asp.Net?

Answer (score 0):

I think u need a sample. Below code help to create custom design and fill the data.

```
   With DgCardVoc
                            '.DataSource = ldstList.Tables(0)

                            .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
                            .ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
                            .EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False
                            If .Columns.Count < 3 Then
                                .Columns.Add("ID", "Id")
                                .Columns.Add("c1", "c1")
                                .Columns.Add("c2", "c2")
                            End If
                            count = ldstList.Tables(0).Rows.Count
                            .Rows.Clear()
                            For i = 0 To count - 1
                                Dim row() As String = {True, ldstList.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0), ldstList.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1), Format(ldstList.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm ttttt")}
                                .Rows.Add(row)
                            Next i
                            .Columns(1).Visible = False
                            For i = 1 To .ColumnCount - 1
                                .Columns(i).ReadOnly = True
                            Next i
                            .Columns(0).Width = "72"
                            .Columns(2).Width = "300"
                            .Columns(3).Width = "185"

                            .RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige
                            .AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(224, 255, 179)
                            .DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Verdana", 12.0F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
                            .DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black
                            .Refresh()
                        End With
```

Do You want direct bind use this

```
.DataSource = ldstList.Tables(0)
```

I hope its help to you..

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a cell, have a javascript function that replaces the control inside the cell with a text-box.

```
function changeToText(control) {
var textElement = document.createElement('INPUT');
var parentElement = control.parentNode;

setValue(control.id, control.innerHTML);

textElement.setAttribute("id", control.id);
textElement.setAttribute("type", "text");
textElement.setAttribute("value", control.innerHTML);

parentElement.replaceChild(textElement, control);
```

set the other cells css property to make it appear as disabled.